# C++ - Functions with the same name

Tags: c++, function, header

I have two different header files I have to include (one is the standard assert.h), both with an assert function. I have no control over these header files (so I can’t change them). I get a compiler error stating the conflict between these 2 functions. How can I specify in my code that the assert function from assert.h should be used to eliminate this compiler error?

Comment: [That's a macro, not a function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert). You'd have to `#undef assert`. I'm not sure how well that would work for you, though.

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting. As you can see, your vague question leads to guessing.

Comment: Side note: You should be using `cassert`, not `assert.h`. Of course the namespace wrapping doesn't matter when it's a macro, though.

Comment: Assuming what your other header contains is really a function declaration, things should be pretty easy: include the other header *first*, then include `<assert.h>`/`<cassert>`. Since the latter defines a macro, it'll hide the function declaration in your previous header.

Comment: I'd be tempted to say: don't use the non-standard header which defines `assert`.  Code which goes around defining things which are defined in the standard library is of very poor quality, and will probably have other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace OtherAssert
{
#include "private_assert.h"
}
//...
void foo()
{
    OtherAssert::assert(true); // non-standard assert
    assert(true); // the one from standard assert.h
}
```

Comment: This may let your code compile, but without more work it (normally) won't link. The linker will look for `OtherAssert::assert`, and since the library was (apparently) contained `::assert` instead, linking will fail (unless all the functions declared in the header are also defined there as inline functions).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Depends on the details, of course. (Perhaps the function is declared inline.)

Comment: correct, that was just an idea of how to resolve the compilation error. I guess a better approach is given in Jerry Coffin's answer above